# Create new sheet with notification - by pressing button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I realise there aren't any buttons, but I'm hoping to use an image with script attached.  When this is pressed, a sheet in the document will be copied and a new standalone sheet created.  I want to be able to set the notification on that new sheet.

I will need to look at installable triggers but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  Is this possible and if so can I also 'push' (i think) an onEdit event onto the new sheet?

I haven't been able to find any scripts that do this.  I was originally hoping I could amend some cells in a template and create a copy, but the notification data is not retained in the copy.

All help / comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are talking about "Toast", if so please check this post:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80213/create-a-popup-in-google-spreadsheet

example: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title);`

Also take a look to this post which has a good example of how to create new sheets:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78096/script-to-create-a-new-worksheet-in-google-spreadsheet

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that Daniel.  The notification I was trying to copy from the original sheet was actually the notification rules, so I can press the button, the sheet is copied to a new spreadsheet and I get an email when the document was edited.

Comment: For anyone else wondering about copying sheets with notification rules intact - I ended up copying the entire spreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy('newss')  Just be aware this gets saved in the root directory, not the folder your document is in - I had tonnes of the little blighters before I realised the code was working.